# Following the constructor execution order in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, virtual, multiple-inheritance

I have the following program in `C++`:

```
class A {
public :
    A(){
        cout << "A::A()" << endl;
    }
    A( int x){
        cout << "A::A(int)" << endl;
    }
};

class B : public A {
public :
    B(){
        cout << "B::B()" << endl;
    }
    B( int x){
        cout << "B::B(int)" << endl;
    }
};

class C : public virtual B {
    public :
    C(){
        cout << "C::C()" << endl;
    }
    C( int x){
        cout << "C::C(int)" << endl;
    }
};

class D : public B {
public :
    D(){
        cout << "D::D()" << endl;
    }
    D( int x) : B(x){
        cout << "D::D(int)" << endl;
    }
};


class E : public C, public virtual
D, public virtual B {
public :
    E(){
        cout << "E::E()" << endl;
    }
    E( int x) : D(x){
        cout << "E::E(int)" << endl;
    }
};


int main() {
    E(5);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to understand what is going to be printed. I'll try to explain how I see the situation. At first we call `E(5)`. In the `E(int)` constructor we have the following syntax: `E(int x) : D(x)` then the `D(x)` constructor should be called (and not the constructors of the inherited classes `class E : public C, public virtual D, public virtual B`, meaning only `D(x)` should be called without `C(),D(),B()`). In the `D` class we need to called the `B()`. This part I don't understand - we called the `D(int)` constructor which has also the syntax: `D(int x) : B(x)` so the `B(x)` should be called and not `B()`. If we need to use the `B()` constructor even if the called constructor `B(x)` than why when we called the `E(5)` constructor, we didn't execute `E()`.

For now, I'll accept that the `B()` should be called first. Then we call the `A()` constructor and execute it and then `B()`. When we get to `D(x)` we call `B(x)` and then `A()` so until now we print:

```
A::A()
B::B()
A::()
B::B(int)
D::D(int)
```

Now we need to go back to `E(5)` and execute it but for some reason the `C()` constructor is called and I don't understand why. We said that if we have the `E(int x) : D(x)` syntax then we execute only `D(x)`. What are the rules/algorithm to follow in those issues?

**EDIT**:
The expected output:

```
A::A()
B::B()
A::A()
B::B(int)
D::D(int)
C::C()
E::E(int)
```

Output from my perspective:

```
A::A() // not fully agree
B::B() // not fully agree
A::A()
B::B(int)
D::D(int)
E::E(int)
```

Comment: Please include the actual output you get when running the program, and the output you think you should get. I would also recommend that you use a debugger to step through the code.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have added the expected output and how I think it should be. I tried to use the debugger (that's how I see that It enters into `C()`).

Comment: Read it up on [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) if the standard is too dry for you.

Comment: I'm getting the expected output.  I'm not sure why you are getting the output from your perspective -- especially why `C` is not being constructed.

Comment: @Eljay I think "expected" means "what actually happens" and "from my perspective" means "what I expect". (That is, pretty much the opposite of what you expect.)

Answer (score 0):

According to the C++ Standard (C++ 17, 15.6.2 Initializing bases and members, p.13)

> 13 In a non-delegating constructor, initialization proceeds in the
>   following order:
>
> (13.1) — First, and only for the constructor of the most derived class
>   (6.6.2), virtual base classes are initialized in the order they appear
>   on **a depth-first left-to-right traversal of the directed acyclic
>   graph of base classes**, where “left-to-right” is the order of
>   appearance of the base classes in the derived class
>   base-specifier-list.

For this class declaration

```
class E : public C, public virtual
D, public virtual B {
public :
    E(){
        cout << "E::E()" << endl;
    }
    E( int x) : D(x){
        cout << "E::E(int)" << endl;
    }
};
```

and this explicit functional conversion expression

```
E(5);
```

the depth-first constructor is the default constructor of the virtual public B.

So the default constructor of the `class B` is called first

```
A::A()
B::B()
```

then the conversion constructor `D( int )` is called

```
A::A()
B::B(int)
D::D(int)
```

and at last the constructor of the non-virtual base `class C` is called

> (13.2) — Then, direct base classes are initialized in declaration
>   order as they appear in the base-specifier-list (regardless of the
>   order of the mem-initializers).

```
C::C()
```

then the control (after initializing non-static data members) is passed to the body of the `constructor E` and the message

```
E::E(int)
```

is outputted.

Take into account that constructors of virtually inherited classes are called first and only once. So the constructor of the class C will not call the constructor of the class B because the corresponding constructor was already called before the call of the constructor of C.

Comment: Thank you. So the steps are: 1. Get the the class which has biggest number of sons and run its default constructor. 2. Check the signature of the called constructor and if it has `E(x) : D(x)` syntax call `D(x)`. 3. Look at all non-virtual classes that `E` extends them and run their default constructor *only*, by order. Is it correct? (please verify that the only default constructor is called because otherwise why when `C()` was called than `B()` wasn't called)

Comment: I just tried to summarize them in order to check if I understand them right. Because for example you didn't said why `B()` was not called when we called `C()`.